# Animate image with jquery Animation effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to animate top menus with jQuery for this website http://www.homeprideflour.co.uk/index.htm

I am not been able to animate products and collectiables menu image hover animation. I am using hover images as background and changing their position with Jquery. Here is my code

```
$('.liproduct a').mouseover(function(){

        $('.prodimg').stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(50% 0px)"}, 
            {duration:600})
        })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $('.prodimg').stop().animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"(50% 100px)"}, 
            {duration:600})
        })
```

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve the mouseover effect same as product menu in above mentioned URL.

Thanks

Comment: you may want to change `{backgroundPosition:"(50% 0px)"}` to `{backgroundPosition:"(50% 0)"}`, as units are insignificant for zero values.

Comment: another thing, you pass the `animate()` with several objects, whereas you should pass a single object with several entries, i.e `{backgroundPosition:"50% 100px", duration:600}` instead of `{backgroundPosition:"50% 100px"}, {duration:600}`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but ths is how I would approach:

```
var $prodImg = $('.prodimg');
$('.liproduct a').on("hover",function(){
        $prodImg.stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(50% 0px)"},
            {duration:600})
        },
        function(){
        $prodImg.stop().animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"(50% 100px)"},
            {duration:600})
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Roger, yeah, it approach is also an good one. However, with this it still display normal animation like slideup. If you mouse hover on referred website "Shop" menu, it displays simple animation, i am able to achieve this however not able to achieve the animation that is on the mouse hover of "products" menu.

Comment: The products grows in size rather than slides up so you would need a separate effect for this instance. Not sure if you can animate background sizes though

Comment: well the image is increasing in size right? The original is done in flash. You could try a zoom effect but again, you will need a separate effect for this instance.